# Slick - implicit conversion of Long to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Slick 2.1
Scala 2.11.7

Cannot get implicit conversions for Long <-> java.sql.Timestamp or java.sql.Date working.  I have them working for other conversions, such as JodaTime.DateTime <-> java.sql.Timestamp...

For example, error returned on query:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: 
timestamp with time zone >= bigint Hint: No operator matches 
the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. 
Position: 325
```

These are the implicits and they are definitely imported properly to be in scope:

```
implicit val LongToTimestamp = MappedColumnType.base[Long, Timestamp](
longTS => new Timestamp(longTS),
sqlTS => sqlTS.getTime
)

implicit val LongToDate = MappedColumnType.base[Long, java.sql.Date](
longTS => new java.sql.Date(longTS),
sqlDate => sqlDate.getTime
)
```

I have also tried using java.lang.Long instead:

```
implicit val LongToTimestamp = MappedColumnType.base[java.lang.Long, Timestamp](
longTS => new Timestamp(longTS),
sqlTS => sqlTS.getTime
)

implicit val LongToDate = MappedColumnType.base[java.lang.Long, java.sql.Date](
longTS => new java.sql.Date(longTS),
sqlDate => sqlDate.getTime
)
```

What am I missing here?  Thank you!

--

additional info:

The query method is defined as (queued is a java.sql.Timestamp) :

```
def getJobs(jobTypeId: Short, onOrAfter: DateTime): Seq[JobRow] = {
 val q1 = for{j <- Jobs if j.jobTypeId === jobTypeId && j.queued >= onOrAfter.getMillis} yield j
 db.withSession{ implicit s =>
   q1.buildColl[Seq]
 }
}
```

The table definition:

```
class Jobs(tag: Tag) extends Table[JobRow](tag, "job") {

def jobId = column[Long]("job_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.NotNull)

def jobTypeId = column[Short]("job_type_id", O.NotNull)

def queued = column[Long]("queued", O.NotNull)

def * = (jobId, jobTypeId, queued) <>((JobRow.apply _).tupled, JobRow.unapply_ )

def pk = primaryKey("job_pk", jobId)
}
```

Comment: The issue is not with your mappings, but with your query - can you show us how you are generating the query?  (The Long is being bound as-is, not converted to a Timestamp, resulting in the error).  Alternatively, it's possible that your implicits are being shadowed by Slick's default implicits.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.  I added the table definition and query example. It feels like your 2nd idea where Slick's default implicits are taking hold and mine are ignored.  Don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that the underlying `queued` column in Postgres is not a `bigint` but a `timestamp with time zone`.  However, in your `Jobs` table definition for Slick you say that the column is a `Long`.  Slick already knows how to bind a Long to a query, so it never tries to use your implicit to convert the Long into another type that it does know how to bind.

Ideally you would just use a `sql.Timestamp` as your `Jobs.queued` column type (which is what your comment on your query snippet seems to indicate you *think* it is):

```
def queued = column[Timestamp]("queued", O.NotNull)
// As opposed to your example where this is
// def queued = column[Long]("queued", O.NotNull)
```

Or, you can create a Slick wrapper for the `to_timestamp(double)`:

```
val toTimestamp = SimpleFunction.unary[Double, Timestamp]("to_timestamp")
val q1 = for {
  j <- Jobs
  if j.jobTypeId === jobTypeId && j.queued >= toTimestamp(onOrAfter.getMillis)
} yield j
```

Finally, you can add an automatic cast to your Postgres DB to convert.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  I naively thought my implicit would be used since Slick doesn't have a Long <-> Timestamp binding.  Is there a solution where Long <->Timestamp conversion can be done on the Slick side without involving DB functions or features?  I've since moved on using ZonedDateTime in the my model, with an implicit, but this still bugged me.

Comment: The problem is that you told Slick that the column is a `Long` - Slick doesn't double-check your schema against the actual table's schema, so it happily binds the `Long` from `getMillis` to the query, resulting in *Postgres* throwing the error.  If you changed from `def queued = column[Long]` to `def queued = column[Timestamp]` you'd get different errors *at compile time* in your `getJobs` method, which you could then resolve.

Comment: if column[Timestamp] is used, but Long is maintained the JobRow class, would by implicit conversions between Long <-> Timestamp work?  Or would I need to define a custom conversion in the def * = ... line?

Comment: You would need to do a custom conversion in the mapping `*` method.